# Include my Nuget README in my Nuget Package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I maintain a few tiny Nuget Packages.

I have a Nuget README file in the git repository, and the `.nupkg` file is auto-built by VS, based on the "Package" config, stored in the `.csproj` file.

Whenever I need to release a new versio of the package, I upload the `.nupkg` file to nuget, in the web UI, and then it asks me for any documentation, at which point I have to manually upload the README file.

Is there any way to put that README file *in* the `.nupkg` so that I don't have to manually upload it every time?

Comment: You can add a [readme.txt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#add-a-readme-and-other-files) file to the NuGet package via the .nuspec file or if you are using [NuGet's built-in Pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli#adding-a-readme-and-other-files) by adding an item to your project. You do not get rich formatting of say a .md file though.

Comment: Bah! That second one seems really close! I can now put the `README.*` file into the nuget package (and confirm it's there, if I open it in the NugetPackageExplorer). But the Nuget upload interface doesn't recognise it :(

Comment: Have sent a message to NuGet.org asking how this is supposed to work. Will update if they give a response.

Comment: There seems to be a plan to allow a README.md file to be included in the NuGet package. There is a spec which is in review status - https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Packaging-Documentation-within-the-nupkg

Comment: Nuget support have confirmed that my current workflow is the only option available, currently. But also pointed out the Issue that @MattWard linked to, as a "future plan".

Comment: @MattWard you want to post that as an answer, for Internet Points?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NuGet have now added support to make this JustWork.

Announcement on the Issue thread: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6873#issuecomment-833829727
Announcement Blog post: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/add-a-readme-to-your-nuget-package/

All you need to do is reference the `README.md` file in the `.csproj`, using the `PackageReadmeFile` tag. If the README.md is in the git root (i.e. where GitHub auto-detects it) then it will look like this:

```
<PackageReadmeFile>README.md</PackageReadmeFile>
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but it did not popup upon installation in VS2022.

Comment: @ScubaSteve *what* didn't pop-up, upon installation of *what*?

Comment: Sorry, I was searching for how to get the readme to popup upon installation of the nuget package.  I was switching between tabs and thought this answer was pertaining to that subject.

Comment: (Though side note ... *did* you find any such functionality? It's not a thought that had ever occurred to me?)

Comment: Yeah, I was able to get it to work. The readme must be a .txt file and not a .md file.  You do not set it with the PackageReadmeFile tag.  Instead you `<ItemGroup><Content Include="readme.txt"><Pack>True</Pack><PackagePath>\</PackagePath</Content></ItemGroup>`.  It's a bit of a pain, but I have both a txt file and a md file so that the txt file pops up when installed and the md file is there when viewing the actual nuget package page.

Answer (score 3):

i do this via the csprj. file.
I created a .netstandard project and added a readme.txt.

add following to the x.csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="readme.txt" pack="true" PackagePath="." />
</ItemGroup>
```

When installing the nuget the first time the file will be displayed in VS.
There is somewhere in the internet a artikel describing the solution, but i cannot find it now.

[image]

Here my complete csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net471;net35</TargetFrameworks>
   .....
    <FileVersion>1.0.1.11</FileVersion>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.1.11</AssemblyVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.6" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="readme.txt" pack="true" PackagePath="." />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is not a way to do this, but it is WIP.

The new spec under review: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Embedding-and-displaying-NuGet-READMEs
This issue for this feature: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6873